# PowerShell Add an AD user from the child domain to a group in the parent domain

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

I am trying to remove an AD user from the child domain from a group in the parent domain using powershell script.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members jdoe -confirm: $false
Error message: Cannot find and object with identity: "jdoe" under: DC: corp, DC:hello, DC=com
```

so, I did

```
$user = Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "jdoe"} -Server child.corp.hello.com

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -confirm: $false

Error message: The specified account name is not a member of the group
```

then, I did

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.DistinguishedName -confirm: $false

Error Message: A referral was returned from the server.
```

How can I remove the user from the group that's in a parent domain?

Comment: run `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User` what is the results? can you see the `$group` in the list?

Comment: yup, I can see the group

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set-ADObject` to remove the cross-domain entry from the `member` attribute of the group:

```
$user = Get-Aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "jdoe"} -Server child.corp.hello.com
Set-ADObject $group -Remove @{member=$user.DistinguishedName}
```

Comment: I tried it but I get, Cannot find an object with identity 'Group name here" under 'DC=corp, DC=hello, DC=com'

Comment: Make sure you target a global catalog in the domain where `$group` exists

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean